# values not affecting in textboxes after deleting

Tags: c#

i have kept delete button in a gridview.now if i am deleting values in grid, it is working and particular rows are deleted.but the textboxes values which are already binded from grid is not changing its values after deleting a row from grid.

```
protected void gvInvoicePart_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
try
    {  
        SetRowData();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex]);
                drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
                gvInvoicePart.DataSource = dt;
                gvInvoicePart.DataBind();

                for (int i = 0; i < gvInvoicePart.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                        gvInvoicePart.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString(i - 1);

                }


                SetPreviousData();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        LogEntry.Write("ClientToDoList_Invoice_gvInvoicePart_RowDeleting", Ex);
        Response.Redirect("../ErrorMessage.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify textboxes values which are already binded from grid

Comment: You do not have to rebind the datasource after changing it.
Remove the lines `gvInvoicePart.DataSource = dt;` and `gvInvoicePart.DataBind();`.

Comment: Does the data come back after the gridview is getting binded and the gridview data is getting deleted just for time being when you click on Delete button. Is this the scenario?

Comment: What happens in `SetPreviousData();`?